# Is it possible to get alerts for the comments/responses on my threads in all the stack sites?

Tags: support, discussion

I am using several StackExchange sites. Very often I need to go through the sites one by one to see if there are new comments/responses. I am wondering if it is a way to check them once for all?

Could anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Go to your [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/360789/softtimur) and click on the **Inbox** link.

You'll find a link to you network profile just below your photo on your user page, on every site.

If the 'inbox' link is missing, you need to log on.

**Update**

In the late-2011 redesign, the Network Profile link moved to the top-right corner of the use page.